# Android : Scheduling a database call in future

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-context

I want to schedule some code to be executed in future. What I want to be done in future is that the future process should call a webservice and do something, after that it should call the local database that I have (SQLite) and do some update on it.

I was going to use Handler for this purpose. Wherein I'll pass the Runnable object to it, and inside runnable I'll call AsyncTask to call the webservice, and on the onPostExecute I'll call my local db and do the update.

But the problem is that when I call the db, it is going to require a context to open itself. Now I looked up if I can pass null to it, but then it says that it will create an inmemory database, instead of giving my database that I've created already.

Now, I can pass the context info from the place where I am creating the runnable instance, but what exactly happens if I keep my 'context' object alive. That context is not going to be used anywhere but in the database.

What will be the best way to work this through?

Thanks

Comment: You'd be much better off using an `IntentService` for the background work (that is, the network request and database update). Leverage the `AlarmManager` to schedule the request. It also allows the scheduling of repeating events, which is presumably what you'll want, and enable you to do the 'sync' if your app is not currently running or in the foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IntentService`, perform a blocking request so that the service is not killed and then the write to the database both in `onHandleIntent`.

Comment: How can I schedule an IntentService for a particular time in future?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work If you use the handler method that you are speaking of. I don't think you will have any issues (other than stopping your garbage collector from collecting the context) if you retain a reference to the context. To be safe though, I would use the application context to create and retrieve the db, as that context doesn't get garbage collected until the android OS kills your app process, which occurs sometime after a user closes the app.

Comment: Is it that, if I schedule a runnable, then itwill execute only if my app is running?

Comment: @Kraken I have had runnables run after an app closed but, I was setting them to run after a few seconds of the app closing. How long after closing your app do you expect to run the runnable?

Comment: A day. I think I'll go with the AlarmManager + IntentService approach. Thanks alot.